# Duvida if else retornando 0

Tags: c, if, else

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte exercício:

> 10)Uma fruteira está vendendo frutas com a seguinte tabela de preços:
>
> ```
>     Até 5 Kg        Acima de 5 Kg Morango R$ 2,50 por Kg  R$ 2,20 por Kg Maçã    R$ 1,80 por Kg  R$ 1,50 por Kg
> ```
>
> Se o cliente comprar mais de 8 Kg em frutas ou o valor total da compra
>   ultrapassar R$ 25,00, receberá ainda um desconto de 10% sobre este
>   total. Escreva um algoritmo para ler a quantidade (em Kg) de morangos
>   e a quantidade (em Kg) de maças adquiridas e escreva o valor a ser
>   pago pelo cliente.

Escrevi a primeira parte do código mas está retornando R$0,00 ao testar,
que erro cometi? como posso resolver?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main()
{
    float qmor,qmac,totalfru,valormor,valormac,valortotal;
    printf ("Quantidade de Morangos(Kg):");
    scanf ("%f",&qmor);
    printf ("Quantidade de Macas(Kg):");
    scanf ("%f",&qmac);
    totalfru=qmor+qmac;
    valortotal=valormor+valormac;
    if (qmor<=5)
    {
        valormor=2.50*qmor;       
    }
    else
    {
        valormor=2.20*qmor;
    }
    if (qmac<=5)
    {
        valormac=1.80*qmac;
    }
    else
    {
        valormac=1.50*qmac;
    }
    printf ("Valor Total: R$%.2f",valortotal);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
valortotal=valormor+valormac;
```

`valormor` e `valormac` apenas é inicializado com um valor mais abaixo, deverá então trocar essa linha `valortotal=valormor+valormac;` para o fim.

```
    if (qmor<=5)
        valormor=2.50*qmor;

    else
        valormor=2.20*qmor;

    if (qmac<=5)
        valormac=1.80*qmac;

    else
        valormac=1.50*qmac;

    valortotal=valormor+valormac;
```

Comment: muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

O Valor Total deve executar a operação após as variáveis valormore e valormac terem sidos tratadas. Como elas iniciam com o valor 0 no momento da conta elas continuam com esse valor, já que não foi feita nenhuma operação com elas.

Basicamente o que está acontecendo é:

valormore e valormac  começa armazenando o valor 0, em seguida a variável valortotal recebe o valor do resultado da soma dessas duas variáveis. Na sequencia as variaveis valormore e valormac são tratadas e recebem valores diferentes porém a valortotal continua com o mesmo valor do inicio, pois apenas recebeu uma cópia da soma dessas duas variáveis, persistindo o valor 0 nela.